# How to bind Model to `asp-for` tag

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In my asp.net core view i have a list of yes-no question. so instead of creating two radio buttons ( YES and NO) for each question, i want to create partial view that takes boolean as model.

But i am not sure how can bind Model directly to `asp-for` tag so it will create proper id and name attribute

```
@model bool

<div class="radio">
    <label class="control-label">
        <input type="radio" asp-for="model" value="Yes"/>Yes
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label class="control-label">
        <input type="radio" asp-for="model" value="No" />No
    </label>
</div>
```

this is not working. Shows error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'bool' does not contain a definition for 'model' and no
>   extension method 'model' accepting a first argument of type 'bool'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the model directly, you need to prefix it with `@`:

```
<input type="radio" asp-for="@Model" value="Yes" />
```

Comment: Thats worked. Also in order to get it to work i had to put my partial view into `EditorTemplate` folder and use `@Html.EditorFor`